# Why is the bigO of this algorithm m^2*n?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I am trying to determine why the bigO of this algorithm is m^2*n, and why the innermost loop is executing in m^2*n steps.

```
   int m=10, n=15;
   int inLoop = 0, midLoop = 0, outLoop = 0; 

   for(int i=1;i<=m;i++)
   {
    outLoop++; 
        for(int j=1;j<=2*i-1;j++)
        {
            midLoop++; 
            for(int k=1;k<=n;k++)
            {
            inLoop++; 
            }
        }
   }

   System.out.println("Out Loop " + outLoop);
   System.out.println("Mid Loop " + midLoop);
   System.out.println("Inner Loop " + inLoop);
```

When I run this, I get that the inner loop runs 1500 times, the middle loop 100 times, and the outermost loop 10 times.

Before running this code I thought that this code ran the first loop **m** times, the second loop **m^2** times, and the last loop **n** times, which with these values would result in the inner loop output to be 15,000.

Apparently the algorithm seems to be executing the innermost loop in **m^2 * n** steps as opposed to the **m^3*n** steps I believed it would be.

Comment: Why would the middle loop run m^2 times?

Comment: (2i-1) when you work it out (it's a summation) turns out to equal m^2 times. @Compass

Comment: _Before running this code I thought that this code ran the first loop m times, the second loop m^2 times, and the last loop n times_ Either the second loop or the last loop in this line is incorrect then. Either it's m^2*n for the last loop, or another m for the second loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

summation(2i - 1) as i starts at 1 and ends at m is:

2*summation(i) - summation(1) = 2 * (m+1)/2 * m - m = O(m^2)

This is only for the outer and middle loop

The inner loop is straight forward resulting in O(n * m^2)

Comment: So the m^2 is for both the outer and middle loops? I thought the outer loop ran m times, and then the middle loop ran m^2 and so I would have to multiply them to get m^3 * n. Could you explain a little more? @Keeto

Comment: The outer loop runs m times, each time the outer loop runs, the middle loop runs (2*i - 1) times where i is the iteration number of the outerloop.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the idea is clear, that you count how often each loop is repeated, and that it's rather the details that are unclear. Now, in order to ease these things, you can separate these loops and conquer them separately.

For the outermost loop, it is pretty clear that it runs `m` times. That is, its complexity is Θ(m x), with `x` being the complexity of what's inside. For the innermost loop, the case is also pretty simple, it only depends on the value of `n`, which is constant, so its complexity is Θ(n).

The middle loop is the one that is a bit more complicated. Its complexity depends on `i`, but `i` is not constant but the loop variable of the outer loop. However, you can use the average as replacement. In this case the average is pretty simple, which you can visualize if you draw a checkboard. In the first iteration of the outer loop, `i=1`, so `j` will only take a single value `1`. In the second iteration, `i=2` and `j=1..3`. In the third, it's `j=1..5` and so on. If you draw these underneath each other, you get a triangle-like shape. It has the width `1` at the top, the width `2m-1` at the bottom and a height of `m`. It's area is therefore `((2m-1)+1)/2=m`.

Putting this together, you have complexities Θ(m) for the outer and middle loop and Θ(n) for the inner loop, making it Θ(m²n) overall.

Comment: If you were to just run the code I have from above you would see the the middle for loop outputs 100 times, so I do not see how it could be of order m, when it is 100 when m is 10. that alone shows it cant be m

Comment: Multiply the ten from the outer loop with the on-average ten of the inner loop and you get your hundred. Maybe it wasn't clear enough, but the point was handling each loop separately as far as possible.